# Swap every pair of characters in string

Tags: php, string

I'd like to get all the permutations of swapped characters pairs of a string. For example:

Base string: `abcd`

Combinations:

1. `bacd`
2. `acbd`
3. `abdc`

etc.

#### Edit

I want to swap only letters that are next to each other. Like first with second, second with third, but not third with sixth.

What's the best way to do this?

#### Edit

Just for fun: there are three or four solutions, could somebody post a speed test of those so we could compare which is fastest?

#### Speed test

I made speed test of nickf's code and mine, and results are that mine is beating the nickf's at four letters (0.08 and 0.06 for 10K times) but nickf's is beating it at 10 letters (nick's 0.24 and mine 0.37)

Comment: Related concept: [Damerau–Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau-Levenshtein_distance).

Comment: You might want to remove the "etc." and emphasise that you are not interested in all permutations of the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: Markdown hates me today...

```
$input = "abcd";
$len = strlen($input);
$output = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $len - 1; ++$i) {
    $output[] = substr($input, 0, $i)
              . substr($input, $i + 1, 1)
              . substr($input, $i, 1)
              . substr($input, $i + 2);
}
print_r($output);
```

Comment: That doesn't give every possible version though, does it? Unless I'm misunderstanding OP's question.

Comment: HoboBen i ment to swap only letters that are next to each other. like first with second, second with third but not third with sixth.

Answer (score 1):

nickf made beautiful solution thank you , i came up with less beautiful:

```
  $arr=array(0=>'a',1=>'b',2=>'c',3=>'d');
  for($i=0;$i<count($arr)-1;$i++){
  $swapped="";
  //Make normal before swapped
  for($z=0;$z<$i;$z++){
   $swapped.=$arr[$z];
  }
  //Create swapped
  $i1=$i+1;
  $swapped.=$arr[$i1].$arr[$i];

  //Make normal after swapped.     
  for($y=$z+2;$y<count($arr);$y++){
  $swapped.=$arr[$y];

  }
$arrayswapped[$i]=$swapped;
}
var_dump($arrayswapped);
```

Answer (score 1):

A fast search in google gave me that:

http://cogo.wordpress.com/2008/01/08/string-permutation-in-php/

Answer (score 0):

How about just using the following:

```
function swap($s, $i)
{
  $t = $s[$i];
  $s[$i] = $s[$i+1];
  $s[$i+1] = $t;

  return $s;
}

$s = "abcd";
$l = strlen($s);
for ($i=0; $i<$l-1; ++$i)
{
  print swap($s,$i)."\n";
}
```

Comment: why make that function change the string by reference, just to change it back again? Why not just make the change and return the new string?

Comment: I was trying to be smart and avoid string creations. However, it was a bit of a premature optimisation and one that is probably useless in most cases. Also, I hardly know PHP (or its memory model), so I actually don't know whether it was a optimisation. I changed it now; thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly faster solution as its not overusing substr().

```
function swapcharpairs($input = "abcd") {
  $pre = "";
  $a="";
  $b = $input[0];
  $post = substr($input, 1);
  while($post!='') {
    $pre.=$a;
    $a=$b;
    $b=$post[0];
    $post=substr($post,1);
    $swaps[] = $pre.$b.$a.$post;
  };
  return $swaps;
}

print_R(swapcharpairs());
```